# How can i add multiple images using php powerpoint library?

Tags: php

Can u pls tell me how to bind multiple images in powerpoint using php powerpoint library? In the below code i used foreach loop to add multiple images in powerpoint but only one image is adding so pls help me.

```
<?php 
require_once("db_config.php");
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
include 'PHPPowerPoint.php';
include 'PHPPowerPoint/IOFactory.php';
?>
<html>
<h3 align="center">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'];?>  
<br>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</h3>
<body>
<?php 
echo "<div align='center'>";
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
echo "<table align='center' border='1'>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>UserName</th>
</tr>";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='user_id[]' value='".$row['user_id']."' />  </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user_name'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Export PPT' />";
echo "</form></div>";
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['user_id'])){
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

foreach($user_id as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id ='".$selected."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$img = '<img src="images/'.$row["image_name"].'" height="200" width="300"    />';

$objPHPPowerPoint = new PHPPowerPoint();
// block sets slide logo.
$currentSlide = $objPHPPowerPoint->getActiveSlide();
$shape = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
$shape->setPath('images/'.$row["image_name"]);
$shape->setWidth(640); 
$shape->setHeight(480);
$shape->setOffsetX(10);
$shape->setOffsetY(10);

// block sets text for first slide.
$shape = $currentSlide->createRichTextShape();
$shape->setHeight(700);
$shape->setWidth(600);
$shape->setOffsetX(10);
$shape->setOffsetY(500);
$shape->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(        PHPPowerPoint_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER );
$textRun = $shape->createTextRun('FirstName:'.$row["first_name"].'   Lastname:'.$row["last_name"].' UserName:'.$row["user_name"]);
$textRun->getFont()->setBold(true);
$textRun->getFont()->setSize(30);
$textRun->getFont()->setColor( new PHPPowerPoint_Style_Color( '#FFFF' ) );

// block sets text for first slide ends.

$filename = str_replace('.php', '.pptx', __FILE__);
$newname = "PresentationReport-" . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . ".pptx";
$objWriter = PHPPowerPoint_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPPowerPoint, 'PowerPoint2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.pptx', __FILE__));

// block to download file.
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=" . $newname);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filename);
exit();
}
}
else
{

echo "<div align='center'>Please choose the user</div>";
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[How can i add multiple images using php powerpoint library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497643/how-can-i-add-multiple-images-using-php-powerpoint-library)

Two troubles can be indentified in your snippet:

1 - You're calling "new Powerpoint" to each element in foreach, and due this
you always override the previous slide.

2 - You're positioning your shapes in the same x/y offset:

```
$shape->setOffsetX(10);
$shape->setOffsetY(10);
```

So in the foreach all shapes will be stacked.
To a functional solution you'll need to mount a valid algorithm like:

I'll have 4 photos by slide for example so:

```
$resultsFromDataBase = $resultsFromDataBase;

// Array chunk to create a "logic" 4 photos ... jump to the new slide
$resultsBySlide = array_chunk($resultsFromDataBase, 4);

// Each photo needs your independent X offset
// Note the fake values, you need to calculate them
$positionsByIndex = [
    0 => 10,
    1 => 20,
    2 => 30,
    3 => 40
];

foreach ($resultsBySlide as $i => $rows) {
    // 4 photos -> Jump the slide and create another one
    $ppt->createSlide();

    // SlideCount -1 gets your current index
    $slideIndex = $ppt->getSlideCount()-1;
    $currentSlide = $objPHPPowerPoint->getActiveSlide(); 

    foreach ($rows as $position => $row) {
        $shape = $currentSlide->createDrawingShape();
        $shape->setPath('images/'.$row["image_name"]);
        $shape->setWidth(640); 
        $shape->setHeight(480);
        $shape->setOffsetX($positionsByIndex[$position]); // Here the point
        $shape->setOffsetY(10);
    }
}
```

And the last point but not less important: Don't use mysql_* in your project
use: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) instead